# Detect user open devtool in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a quiz system and i want to prevent user from opening devtool or view source code to search it on Google. I have already prevented user using shortcut to open it. But I found out that there is one more way to open the devtool is using view tab and choose developer selection [[image: Open devtool by using view tab]]. So is there any solution to detect user opening devtool and prevent them? Hope that someone can give me an answer soon. Thank you

I Have try to use `window.addEventListener` in useEffect but nothing gonna happened. Here is my source code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleUserKeyPress = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      //prevent user use shortcut to open devtool
      if (event.keyCode === 123) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      if (
        event.getModifierState("Alt") ||
        event.getModifierState("Shift") ||
        event.getModifierState("Meta") ||
        event.getModifierState("Fn") ||
        event.getModifierState("Win")
      ) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("devtoolschange", function (e) {
      console.log("is DevTools open?", e);
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: This is not going to work  when you're done with your project, send it to me and with all your precautions I'll access the answers to all the questions within 5 minutes. Seriously, please don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

***Best way to prevent any shortcut:***

```js
window.onkeydown =
    window.onkeyup =
    window.onkeypress =
        () => {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        };
```

***Prevent users from opening the Dev Tool by right click:***

```js
window.oncontextmenu = () => {
    alert('No way!!!');
    return false;
};
```

***Monitor the window size:***

If the user opens the Dev Tool, the window size will be changed (unless the Dev Tool and main window are separated).

```js
let h = window.innerHeight;
let w = window.innerWidth;
window.onresize = () => {
    if (h !== window.innerHeight || w !== window.innerWidth) {
        // If the user violates the rules, do anything u want :)
        window.location = '...';
    }
};
```

Then, combine these ways together!